# send user to payments URL via form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I want users to be able to enter custom amounts in order to be redirected to paypal. I already have a form for myself to generate payment links that then generate buttons to be sent there but I want a client form to automatically send them to PayPal.

The user should fill out the form and then be sent to `paypal.me/username/12` if 12 was the entered amount entered.

```js
function process()
{
var url="https://paypal.me/username/" + document.getElementById("url").value;
location.href=url;
return false;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return process();" autocomplete="off">
<input type="text" name="pay" id="payamount" autofocus="">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Make Payment" id="pay">
</form>
```

It does send the user to PayPal but to `paypal.me/username/?pay=12` when it needs to be `paypal.me/username/12` Not too sure how to fix this but help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's in `document.getElementById("url").value`? Are you sure it's not `?pay=12`? And it's also possible that PayPal is doing some redirects on their end.

Comment: In the example the id argument does not match the id attribute of the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where the problem is:

`var url="https://paypal.me/username/" + document.getElementById("url").value;`

where is the element with `"url"` `id`?

Now with regards to this:

> It does send the user to PayPal but to paypal.me/username/?pay=12 when
>   it needs to be paypal.me/username/12 Not too sure how to fix this but
>   help would be appreciated.

The reason you're getting ?pay=12 is because your form is by default submitting with get method and that is how properties are embedded into your submitted url. so `pay` is the `name` attribute value of the payamount element.

By understanding your code, below is what should happen:

target the `id="payamount"`  input and not `id="url"` which does not exist on the html you provided.

`var url = "https://paypal.me/username/" + document.getElementById("payamount").value;`

Comment: username is not payamount

Comment: @tim of course... I am not talking about username there... which isn't in his question.. again it will be easier to change that. the problem lies with the pay.. the way it appears on the url when the form is submitted.

Comment: Thank you, think that was an oversight on my part from staring at it for ages :)